# Selecionar todas as tags separadas por "," de toda tabela

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

```
id | tags
1  | tag1,tag2,tag3
2  | tag1,tag2,tag3
```

No db existe a coluna "tags" onde fica "tag1,tag2,tag3..." preciso mostrar todas as tags separadas, no entanto mostra apenas a do primeiro registro, gostaria de pegar as tags de todos, como faço?

```
 $tags =  explode(',', $tags_row);

 foreach ($tags as $item) { 
   echo "< href='#'>$item</a> "; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Exites várias formas de resolver o problema, segue um exemplo:

```
$tags_row = 'tag1, tag2, tag3';

$tags =  explode(',', $tags_row);

foreach ($tags as $item) { 
 echo "<href='#'>{$item}</a><br>"; 
}
```

sua lógica esta correta, para imprimir váriaveis em PHP utilizando  aspas "" dupulas no echo deve utilizar {$variavel} para que o php escape as aspas.